# Securely pass an ID from a view to a controller (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a commenting system within an application. So that the controller knows which `widget` the comment relates to (there are several `widget`s on each page) I'm passing through the `$widget_id` as part of the form post.

However this could easily be DOM hacked, allowing a user to post a comment to any widget they wish. The user ID is easier to handle as that's part of the session.

Is there a more secure method to achieve the same thing? Can flash data be used in this case? All the solutions I've found involve passing the id through the hidden field, but this is in no way secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security through obscurity by itself being a bad idea notwithstanding, you could theoretically encrypt the form data and call it something innocuous:

```
<input type="hidden" name="theme_modifier" value="<?php echo $this->encrypt->encode('widget_name'); ?>">
```

At least this way an attacker will have a harder time guessing what the expected value should be. Especially true since CI uses mcrypt which means the value will change every time even if the unencrypted value is the same.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan - especially given that the fact that I'm not expecting anyone to want to maliciously alter the data (I'm just staying on the side of caution).

I'm going to hold off on marking this as the accepted answer, just in case there's a more standard way to approach this behaviour, but I'll come back and mark it later if nothing else crops up - I'm going to go ahead with this technique for now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool - take your time. I'm secretly hoping there's a more elegant solution that I couldn't think of :) Also, good on you for being paranoid - hope for the best and prepare for the worst.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing it. Don't pass id to hidden field in html.
Just save it in session. Then you may need to load pages related to that user.
Do all the stuff in the controller. Then load pages that should be allow to user.
For example Edit page. Then when user save some data check the currently logged in
user with session and check if user has permission to edit if true then proceed.

Comment: This is currently how I'm verifying the user (through the session) - but this won't work for verifying the widget, as there are several on one page. Think of it like a task list. It's one page with many tasks, each of which can have comments attached. So when the form is submitted it needs to know which task it relates to, currently this is being passed through POST and hidden field, but this could be easily changed in the DOM by an end user.

Comment: Hi raheel, that's essentially the solution being proposed in the other answer, and what I'm now using, in lieu of something a bit more robust! Technically a user could still copy the encoded result into another hidden field - so it's obscure, but not totally secure.